# Getting null value of document.getElementById on first time click a button to show the progress bar in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a progress bar ,working fine on click a button second time. Initially progress bar will be hidden ,on click only it should show and start the progress. But here issue is on first time click it only shows the progress bar and progress is not happening. Document.getElementById value is showing null first time.on second time click progress bar is working. Here is the code below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvngve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div class="w3-light-grey" *ngIf="showIt">
  <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:20%">20%</div>
</div>
<button  (click)="progressbar()">progress</button>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  showIt: boolean = false;
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showIt = false;
  }
  progressbar() {
    this.showIt = true;
    var elem = document.getElementById('myBar');
    console.log(elem);
    var width = 20;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++;
        if (elem != null) {
          elem.style.width = width + '%';
          elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because of `*ngIf` on template. on first click you don't have progress bar with myBar id in template. As a workaround you can change `*ngIf="showIt"` to something like `[style.visibility]="showIt ? 'visible':'hidden'"`
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyqwgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: In my project I have one more div that need to hide after click like that <div class="w3-light-grey" *ngIf="!showIt">
  Hello
</div> , how to handle it in this case ?